# How to use ADC and set flag in Assembly

Tags: adc

I understand what ADC does but I'm not sure how to manage the carry flag. If I use a regular ADD and it overflows, will it automatically set the carry flag to be 1? And if I use ADC and the CF is 1 and it *doesn't* overflow, will it set the CF to be 0? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming intel x86 assembler:
Both ADD and ADC will set the Carry Flag on high-order bit carry or borrow and it will be cleared otherwise.

Using ADC when the CF is 1 and there is no overflow, will result in CF=0.

Comment: can you please explain this behaviour https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015812/8085-strange-behaviour-of-carry-flag

Answer (score 0):

For details, see the official reference at [www.intel.com](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), page 498.

**Description**
Adds the destination operand (first operand), the source operand (second operand), and the carry (CF) flag and stores the result in the destination operand. The destination operand can be a register or a memory location; the source operand can be an immediate, a register, or a memory location. (However, two memory operands cannot be used in one instruction.) The state of the CF flag represents a carry from a previous addition. When an immediate value is used as an operand, it is sign-extended to the length of the destination operand format.
[...]