# 8085- Strange behaviour of Carry flag

Tags: assembly, simulator, 8085

**I am using GNUSim8085**
**(Also the results are same on trainer)**

I was getting familiar  wih `ADC` instruction and the instructions below doesnt seem to work the way i want.

```
stc  ;to make sure carry is set

mvi a,00h  
mvi b,0ffh          

adc b

hlt
```

I expected the carry flag to be set because we are adding 11111111+00000000+00000001 , so that would obviously yield a carry but the carry flag is not set. Why is this working this way. Can you please explain this.

Also why is carry generated in the below code and not in the above code:

```
stc  ;to make sure carry is set

mvi a,7dh  ; 7dh  ==    01111101
mvi b,c8h  ; c8h  ==    11001000        

adc b

hlt
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221505/auxiliary-carry-and-carry-flags-in-8085)?

Comment: (as the answer there suggest, try using another simulator)

Comment: I tried it in the trainer also but the results are same

Comment: Why are you writing `0ffh` instead of `ffh`? The CPU is only 8 bits anyway.

Comment: @helb thats because the simulator "GNUSim8085" wants me to write it that way

Comment: @loudmummer please forget about that i have updated the question

Comment: How do you check if the carry flag is set? Dou you see it in a debugger?

Comment: I tried it on the trainer and also on GNUSim8085

Comment: @helb Some compilers and assemblers require all integer literals to start with a digit, so you need to add a leading 0, even when using the `h` suffix.

Comment: It's clearly a bug. The 8085 manual requires CY to be set if the result does not fit in 8 bits. *Also, it works if* `a` *and* `b` *are reversed.* (`a`=`0ffh`, `b`=`0h`) I.e. the addition is non-commutative in the simulator, which contradicts not only the spec but the underlying math itself…

Comment: @ArneVogel i tried it on the 8085 trainer board also and it results same.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from my previous comment: It is a bug in the function `_eef_inst_func_add_with_carry_i` in `src/8085-instructions.c` of the GNUSim8085 source code. Here is the current source code from the `master` branch, [off of GitHub](https://github.com/GNUSim8085/GNUSim8085) (rev. 88a604043a2b7f153ff97e2c3026145814f7fc39):

```
eef_data_t data_1;

/* I'm not sure abt the new code
 * Old code:
 if (op == '+')
 data_1 = data + sys.flag.c;
 else
 data_1 = data - sys.flag.c;
*/
data_1 = data + sys.flag.c;

/* check for flags */
sys.flag.c = 0; 
sys.flag.c = (_eef_is_carry (sys.reg.a, data, op)
              || _eef_is_carry (sys.reg.a, data_1, op));
```

…

See [lines 326 ff. here](https://github.com/GNUSim8085/GNUSim8085/blob/ebbda5941092781acf1f60dd1c2b95828cbf3d2e/src/8085-instructions.c).

Let's ignore for now:

- the redundant assignment `sys.flag.c = 0;`
- the comment that points towards an earlier bug related to the SBB instruction

The bug is due to `eef_data_t` being an alias of `guint8`, and the code checking whether *either* the addition of `data` or `data_1`, which is `data + sys.flag.c`, converted back to an `eef_data_t`, to the accumulator, overflows, and setting the carry flag accordingly.

If `data == 0xff`, then `data_1 == 0` because `data + sys.flag.c == 0x100`, but the result is converted back to an 8-bit unsigned integer in the assignment, losing the most significant bit. Then, `eef_is_carry` is used to check whether either `0 + 0xff`, or `0 + 0` overflows, *neither of which is the case*. Therefore, the carry bit is cleared. But the actual addition, of course, is `0 + 0x100`, which definitely overflows.

I stand by my previous claim that this is a bug. It is illogical to leave the carry flag unset despite the fact that there should be a carry, mathematically, according to the acknowledged rules of long addition. The 8085 specification describes no such special case. And, even if the exception was valid, don't you agree it should be well-documented?

Most importantly, an ADC that behaves like this simply does not work reliably in common use cases. The reason why ADC instructions at the hardware level even exists is to increase speed (and reduce code size) of multi-word additions relative to the ugly alternative of using comparisons and branching. If ADC does not correctly detect all carry conditions, then the command is insufficient, and even useless, in implementing generic multi-word addition. There is no point in having a broken ADC, compared to none at all, in my opinion. (As I stated previously, due to this bug, the ADC also violates the law of commutativity `a + b == b + a`.)

That said, you pointed out that your trainer board exhibits the same behavior. I do not have an 8085 trainer board, and you did not say which one you have, so I cannot reproduce this behavior. I think it is possible that your trainer board has the same bug as GNUSim8085. Depending on whether there is an 8085 clone on the board, it is even possible that this is an unfortunate case of "bug for bug compatibility" with GNUSim8085. This is however, all speculation at this point.

Comment: Looks like a similar bug to [Assembly ADC (Add with carry) to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154170), another C implementation of add-with-carry.  A single compare isn't enough to get the carry-out when there are 2 inputs + a carry-in.  (Although here it looks like they're trying to get it right by ORing together the carry checks for `a+b` and `data_1 + carry_in`)